# Splash screen narrowed inside

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, android-fullscreen

I used an image as background of splash screen, it's been resized for different pixel densities:

hdpi - 480x800
mdpi - 320x480
xhdpi - 768x1280
xxhdpi- 1080x1920
xxxhdpi - 1440x2560

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/launcher"/>

</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Launcher" parent="BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/grey_light</item>
    </style>
```

It works fine on emulator, however on Samsung Galaxy M20, A7, S9 etc (resolution 2340x1080, screen density xhdpi) it looks narrowed inside. Any solution for that?

[Nexus 4 (xhdpi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npJNe.png)

[Samsung Galaxy M20 (xhdpi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr7fY.jpg)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
      android:name="com.demo.app.MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomHolder"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_tabbar" />

            <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/bottombar_elevation"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:adSize="BANNER"
                app:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/myDrawerBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_top"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
app:layout_behavior="com.demo.app.util.CustomScrollingViewBehavior">

<com.demo.app.util.layout.DisableableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.demo.app.util.layout.DisableableViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, still narrowed inside, screenshot in my last comment under your answer

Comment: Show us your xml please

Comment: i copied splash_screen.xml and posted above along with styles.xml

Comment: Where you calling `splash_screen`  xml. Please provide main xml

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya in AndroidManifest.xml, posted above.

Comment: please provide screenshot,that will help

Comment: Kindly provide your activity main xml

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya up

Comment: Show `activity_main_content`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya up

Comment: splash_screen drawble  calling from any ImageView tags?

Comment: no, it's called in splash_screen.xml only. The thing is there are devices with different screen resolution that use drawables from xhdpi folder. It looks fine on Nexus 4 emulator, but narrowed on Samsung Galaxy M20 which has thinner and longer screen.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Read official guideline about [**`Support different pixel densities`**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

> To provide good graphical qualities on devices with different pixel
>   densities, you should provide multiple versions of each bitmap in your
>   app—one for each density bucket, at a corresponding resolution.

```
drawable-ldpi        //240x320
drawable-mdpi        //320x480
drawable-hdpi        //480x800
drawable-xhdpi       //720x1280
drawable-xxhdpi      //1080X1920
drawable-xxxhdpi     //1440X2560
```

And add this in your manifest

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Rectify your xhdpi

Comment: i resized the xhdpi image, it's still narrowed inside. [image](https://i.imgur.com/5nZ0sYP.png), [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/o4kEkh6.jpg)